# ffmpeg: How to trim a video with every nth frame

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to generate a video preview with every Nth frame, for example I have a 2 minutes video, now I want to trim it down to 10 seconds, the output video should include every Nth frame of the original full video. This is what I got up to, it selects the correct frames but the mp4 is still 2 minute. How do I trim it to 10 seconds?

`./ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:02:00 -i 12skyline.mp4 -r 10/100 -an out.mp4`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am not sure it is the best solution but the following command should work:  `ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:02:00 -i input.mp4 -vf "select=not(mod(n\,10)),setpts='N/FRAME_RATE/TB'" -vsync vfr out.mp4`